# CakePHP - Disallow add action in scaffolding

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to disallow users without permission from being able to add and delete records from a certain model, but still allow them to view and edit the records.

I know how to disable the "add" and "delete" actions, but in the scaffolding, there will still be buttons labeled "New X" and "Delete X"

Yes, I know that a possible solution to this question is "don't use scaffolding, bake the views."  But I want to know: is this possible with scaffolding alone?

I've done some really neat tricks with scaffolding by modifying `$this->paginate` and `$this->Model->hasAndBelongsToMany` according to user permissions, and my previous work makes me think that this might be possible, but Internet and documentation searches are getting me nowhere.

Comment: What's the version of CakePHP that you are using?

Comment: Don't use scaffold :P  Use [Crud](https://github.com/friendsofcake/crud) plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a way to do that is to [customize scaffolding Views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/scaffolding.html#customizing-scaffold-views). You are able to get the source used for those templates from cake core `Cake\View\Scaffolds` and place them in the destinations regarded in the documentation, then edit them to hide what do you want.

For example:
in index.ctp there is the following snippet that generates actions list:

```
echo '<td class="actions">';
        echo $this->Html->link(__d('cake', 'View'), array('action' => 'view', ${$singularVar}[$modelClass][$primaryKey]));
        echo ' ' . $this->Html->link(__d('cake', 'Edit'), array('action' => 'edit', ${$singularVar}[$modelClass][$primaryKey]));
```

Remove edit from it or any thing else you want to modify.

Also you may use , indeed should, use `beforeScaffold` callback method of the controller something like the following:

```
class MyController extends AppController{
public function beforeScaffold(){
  parent::beforeScaffold();
  if ($this->request->params['action'] == 'edit'){
    $this->redirect('/?msg=notallowed');
  }

}

}
```

Comment: This works, and is definitely a decent solution, but it doesn't take associations into account.  So I can write things in the customized scaffolds like `if(!isset($noDeletePermission))` to remove the New and Delete buttons from controller X when that user doesn't have permission to do that to model X.  But then you get to model Y, which belongs to model X, and you see see those `New X` and `Delete X` buttons again.  Is there some way to disallow a specific action on a specific model, and have that button not appear anywhere?  And if not, is this possible in CakePHP 3.0 or the Crud plugin?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, in this case, since, all controllers are inherited from `AppController` I think that to apply this solution in the `AppController` to make it available for all the controllers. @howrad

Comment: A clearer example: I want User A to see `New X`, `Delete X`, `New Y`, and `Delete Y`.  User B should only see `New Y` and `Delete Y` and shouldn't see `New X` and `Delete X`.  These buttons should be hidden in both XController and YController, and Y belongsTo X.

Comment: @howrad If you could able to implement that without scaffold in the controller's actions, so make this implemetaion in the `beforeScaffold()` method described above.